# Highcharts plotbands different per category

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am attempting to create the following chart:

[image]

However I can't seem to get the plotbands to work in this way; right now, they fill the entire axis:

I am not sure if I should use annotations instead, but so far I haven't gotten it to work. What can I try next?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container',{
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: "hello world",
                style: {
                    visibility: 'hidden'
                }
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                width: 400,
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: true,
                allowHTML:true,
                chartOptions: {
                    chart: {
                        marginLeft: 175,
                        marginRight: 175
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        line: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: 14

                                },
                                verticalAlign: "top",
                                useHTML: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineWidth: 2,
                tickWidth: 2,
                tickLength: 20,
                plotBands: [{
                    color: 'rgba(231, 23, 60, 0.5)', // Color value
                    from: 5, // Start of the plot band
                    to: 6.2 // End of the plot band
                },
                {
                    color: 'rgba(53, 101, 237, 0.5)', // Color value
                    from: 1, // Start of the plot band
                    to: 3 // End of the plot band
                }
                ],
                title: {
                    align: 'high',
                    offset: -40,
                    text: 'mmol/L',
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        fontSize: 15
                    },
                    rotation: 0,
                    y: -20
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 7,
                labels: {
                    x: -10,
                    y: -3,
                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.value != 0) {
                            if (this.value < 8) {

                                return this.value;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: "400",
                        lineHight: "20",
                        padding: "0",
                        fontSize: "13"
                    }
                }

            },
            
    annotations: [{
        shapes: [{
            point: '0',
            type: 'circle',
            r: 10
        }, {
            point: '3',
            type: 'rect',
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            x: -10,
            y: -25
        }, {
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 3,
            type: 'path',
            points: ['0', '1', {
                x: 6,
                y: 195,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
            }],
            markerEnd: 'arrow'
        }],
        labels: [{
            point: {
                x: 6,
                y: 195,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
            }
        }]
    }],
            xAxis: {
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                accessibility: {
                    rangeDescription: 'Range: 2010 to 2020'
                },
                categories: [2018, 2019]
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: 14

                        },
                        verticalAlign: "top",
                        useHTML: true,
                        format: '<div style="max-width: 10ch; text-align: center;">{y}<br/>mmol/L</div>'


                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: '',
                color: "black",
                data: [5.4, 3],
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                }
            }],
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of `plotBand` shape is not possible from the API level, but you can simulate it in several ways. Example configurations:

---

***SVG Renderer:***

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this;

        if (chart.rects) {
          chart.rects = chart.rects.destroy();
        }

        chart.rects = chart.renderer.g('rects').attr({
          zIndex: 1
        }).add();

        let x = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(1),
          y = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(4),
          width = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(2) - chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(1),
          height = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(2) - chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(4);

        chart.rect = chart.renderer.rect(x, y, width, height)
          .attr({
            fill: 'grey'
          }).add(chart.rects)

        chart.rect = chart.renderer.rect(chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(3), y, width, height)
          .attr({
            fill: 'grey'
          }).add(chart.rects)
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wst607ub/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

---

***Annotations:***

```
 annotations: [{
  draggable: false,
    shapes: [{
      points: [{
                x: 1,
                y: 2,
                xAxis: 0, // xAxis reference used, use xAxis value
                yAxis: 0  // yAxis reference used, use xAxis value
            }, {
                x: 2,
                y: 2,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
            }, {
                x: 2,
                y: 4,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
            }, {
                x: 1,
                y: 4,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
            }],
      type: 'path'
    }]
  }]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uvxzp6o7/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

---

***Polygon series:***

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Polygons',
    type: 'polygon',
    color: 'grey',
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    states: {
      inactive: {
        opacity: 1,
      },
    },
    data: [
      [1, 2],
      [2, 2],
      [2, 4],
      [1, 4],
      null, // allows multiple polygons         
      [3, 2],
      [4, 2],
      [4, 4],
      [3, 4],
    ]
  }]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4n7ep3k2/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.polygon

---

Take note that `annotations` and `polygon` series require the module to be included.